# Access rows in an automatically generated table using Javascript+JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to JQuery. I have two tables: table1 is hardcoded in HTML and table2 is generated using javascript from an array loaded from a csv file. After the second table is displayed, I want to highlight (and later process) the row that user clicks using a JQuery. Simplified code below.

Hardcoded table:

```
<table id="table1">
    <tr> <td>cell1</td><td>cell2</td><td>cell3</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>cell4</td><td>cell5</td><td>cell6</td> </tr>
</table>
```

Generate table from an array with id "data" (works fine):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function createTable(){
    var content = "";
    data.forEach (function(row){
        content += "<tr>";
        row.forEach (function(cell)
            { content += "<td>" + cell + "</td>"; });
        content += "</tr>"; });
    document.getElementById("table2").innerHTML = content; }
</script>
```

JQuery script to do whatever to a row in the table, for example display an alert when a row is clicked:

```
<script>
$("tr").click(function()
{
    alert("do something"); 
}); 
</script>
```

This code doesn't work for the generated table2. It does work only if I try to highlight the whole table (using `$("table")`) but not when I try to highlight any of its elements (tr, td). It works perfectly for the hardcoded table1.

I tried using different elements like `$("#table2 :td")`, `$("#table2 td")` and so on but to no avail. How come I can access the whole table but not its elements?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize what I am looking for is called "delegated events".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamically created elements, you need to use:

```
$('body').on("click", "#your_element",function(){

});
```

OR

```
$("#your_element").on("click",function(){

});
```

Comment: Worked perfect, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You need event delegation for dynamically generated element. Try like below.

```
$('body')on('click', 'tr', function() {
    alert("do something"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason why your click does not work is because,

```
$("tr").click(function(){...})
```

This event is registered on all existing elements but your dynamic rows are yet to be rendered. For this reason you should use **[delegates](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)**.

You can do something like:

```
$(document).on("click", "tr", function(){...})
```

But since you already have `ID`, you should try:

```
$("#table2").on("click", "tr", function(){...});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use live for dynamically added content.

```
$('#table2 tr').on( 'click', function(){
    alert("do something"); 
    console.log(this)
});
```

Comment: From http://api.jquery.com/live/: _"As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers."_

Comment: ah, yes @VictorAlencarSantos. Thanks for brief.